# Rails postgresql DB connection fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm very new to Ruby and postgres.

Below is my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: test_database
  username: postgresql
  password: mypassword
  host: localhost
  encoding: utf8
```

The user exists and I'm, able to login using same credentials in phpPgadmin. But when I start rails server and go to home page of app, I get `FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgresql"`.

Edit: In case pghba.conf matters,

```
# TYPE  DATABASE          USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
#local    all             all                                     peer
local     all             postgres                                md5
local     all             postgresql                              md5
```

Could anyone please help ?

Comment: Can you log in to the command-line client with those credentials?

Comment: Did you Restart Postgresql server? See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open PostgreSQL client authentication configuration file

```
vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

This file manage below stuffs

1. Which hosts are allowed to connect
2. How clients are authenticated
3. Which PostgreSQL user names they can use
4. Which databases they can access

By default Postgresql uses IDENT-based authentication. All you have to do is allow username and password based authentication for your network or webserver. IDENT will never allow you to login via -U and -W options. Append following to allow login via localhost only:

```
local   all all         trust
host    all 127.0.0.1/32    trust
```

Save and close the file. ***Restart Postgresql server:***

```
service postgresql restart   OR
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

It should work

Comment: Find pg_hba.conf in /etc/postgresql/X.X/main (replace X.X with your release number) if you're running Debian server.

Answer (score 1):

I can find my **pg_hba.conf** file in the path:

```
/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who still can't find their **pg_hba.conf** file, I'm using PostgreSQL v9.2 and I found mine in:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/pg_hba.conf
```

Comment: Same here, CentOS 6.6.  Also, this file was owned by postgres, so I had become the postgres user to access it, ($ sudo su postgres).