# How to solve error of Ident authentication in Rails?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

I have setup [Rail application](https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter) in my local server. And I am using Postgresql database.

But it creates error :

Error message:
    FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "nobody" (PG::Error)

Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::UnknownError

Backtrace:

```
File    Line    Location
0   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb     1208    in `initialize'
1   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb     1208    in `new'
2   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb     1208    in `connect'
3   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb     326     in `initialize'
4   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb     28  in `new'
5   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb     28  in `postgresql_connection'
6   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   315     in `new_connection'
7   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   325     in `checkout_new_connection'
8   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   247     in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
9   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   242     in `loop'
10  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   242     in `block in checkout'
11  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb     211     in `mon_synchronize'
12  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   239     in `checkout'
13  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   102     in `block in connection'
14  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb     211     in `mon_synchronize'
15  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   101     in `connection'
16  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   410     in `retrieve_connection'
17  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb  171     in `retrieve_connection'
18  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb  145     in `connection'
19  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb   130     in `replace_bind_variables'
20  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb   117     in `sanitize_sql_array'
21  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb   28  in `sanitize_sql_for_conditions'
22  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb     324     in `build_where'
23  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb     136     in `where'
24  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/querying.rb   9   in `where'
25  /var/www/PCMI/zil/app/models/order.rb   8   in `'
26  /var/www/PCMI/zil/app/models/order.rb   1   in `'
27  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb     251     in `require'
28  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb     251     in `block in require'
29  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb     236     in `load_dependency'
30  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb     251     in `require'
31  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb     359     in `require_or_load'
32  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@openmunicipalities.org/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb     313     in `depend_on'
33  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb     225     in `require_dependency'
34  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb     439     in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
35  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb     438     in `each'
36  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb     438     in `block in eager_load!'
37  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb     436     in `each'
38  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb     436     in `eager_load!'
39  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb   53  in `block in '
40  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb  30  in `instance_exec'
41  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb  30  in `run'
42  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb  55  in `block in run_initializers'
43  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb  54  in `each'
44  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb  54  in `run_initializers'
45  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@odomain/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb   136     in `initialize!'
46  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb   30  in `method_missing'
47  /var/www/PCMI/zil/config/environment.rb     5   in `'
48  config.ru   3   in `require'
49  config.ru   3   in `block in '
50  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb  51  in `instance_eval'
51  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb  51  in `initialize'
52  config.ru   1   in `new'
53  config.ru   1   in `'
54  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  225     in `eval'
55  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  225     in `load_rack_app'
56  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  157     in `block in initialize_server'
57  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb     563     in `report_app_init_status'
58  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  154     in `initialize_server'
59  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   204     in `start_synchronously'
60  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   180     in `start'
61  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  129     in `start'
62  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb     253     in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
63  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    132     in `lookup_or_add'
64  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb     246     in `block in spawn_rack_application'
65  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    82  in `block in synchronize'
66  < td=""> <> prelude>    10:in `synchronize'
67  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    79  in `synchronize'
68  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb     244     in `spawn_rack_application'
69  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb     137     in `spawn_application'
70  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb     275     in `handle_spawn_application'
71  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   357     in `server_main_loop'
72  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   206     in `start_synchronously'
73  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain/gems/passenger-3.0.17/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server
```

config/database.yml

```
development:

  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: PCMI
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: postgres


test: &TEST

  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: PCMI 
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: postgres

production:

  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: PCMI
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
```

Please help me for solve this error..

If you need any further information regarding these error then plz inform.

Thank you.

Comment: please post your config/database.yml file

Comment: I post my config/database.yml file.

Comment: You are using the same database for development and test.  This can be problematic as you are developing your application.  But I don't that's the cause of your connection issue.  First log into the command line client (psql) and make sure your credentials work for the database.  After that, refere to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491537/rails-postgresql-db-connection-fails) regarding how to set up your client authentication file so that you can connect to it with username/password on localhost.

Comment: Can you connect to the database using other tools?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has two kinds of authentication modes. One is through Unix socket authentication, meaning that PostgreSQL checks the user of the process that's connecting to PostgreSQL, and then checking whether that user is authorized to access the database. This kind of authentication mode is what you usually use when you access PostgreSQL from the command line through the `pg` command.

The second one is the password-based authentication that you're already familiar with.

It looks like you didn't setup password authentication properly for the "postgres" user. On top of that, your application is running as the "nobody" user, so PostgreSQL can't Unix socket authenticate your app.

The solution is to make a PostgreSQL username/password authentication entry, and filling that in your database.yml.